# how i can diplay GROUP_CONCAT values in php

Tags: php, sql, pdo

[sqlQueryImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPOWg.png) [ThisWhatIgetinPHP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xiGe.png)

**i have tried this but it keeps displaying me just the first image of every article i don't know how display multiple image for one article**

```
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT article.titreArticle, article.textArticle,
    article.idArticle, article.dateArticle, GROUP_CONCAT(images.images) AS IMG
    FROM article LEFT JOIN images
        ON article.idArticle = images.idArticle
    GROUP BY article.idArticle");
    for ($i = 0;
    $row = $result->fetch();
    $i++){
    ?>
     <h1 style="text-align: center"><?php echo $row['idArticle']; ?></h1>
        <hr>

        <img style="width: 300px" src="images/<?php if($row ['IMG'] !=null ) {
            $value = $row['IMG'];
        }

        $values = explode(",", $value);
        echo $values[0];

       ?>">
```

Comment: Your query looks correct to me.  Can you provide some sample data which explains the problem?  AFAIK this should not be happening here.

Comment: i  have a problem with fetching multiple image in php otherwise my sql query it works well only i can fetch the first image for my article while each article have multiples images don't know why but it keeps displaying the first image

Comment: Your comment does nothing to help here, because it just repeats the question, which is incomplete, because you never showed us any data.  Please show some data and make your problem reproducible.

Comment: i added an image you can see the problem

Comment: and line 31 is this line of code: 
 $values = explode(",", $value);

Comment: You have some other PHP errors in there from what I can see.  Maybe the script is dying at some point.

Comment: my php script works well only it has some error with Group_Concat while displaying images and i don't know why

Comment: This is why I keep (3rd time) asking you for data.  If we can rule out a problem on MySQL itself, then this would leave the PHP script as the only candidate for error.  So, can you run the raw MySQL query and get the results you expect?

Comment: i hope the second image helps you for solving my problem

Comment: Your query is working fine.  Are you sure that the article in question actually has more than one image associated with it?  One of the articles in your screen shot has no images, and another only has one image.

Comment: yes im sure and  you can see at my sql picture one of my article has more than one image.
about the first article it don't have any image the second have 1 image and the third has 3 images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aim of GROUP_CONCAT is to return each value within each GROUP, concatenated in the same field.

You expect to have several images for certain groups, however you only display one image, the first one encountered : `echo $values[0];`

If you want to display all images of a group, you have to make a second loop on your array of images, to print each element.

So you have your main loop on row, and a second loop on images.

Try this:

```
<?php

$result = $db->prepare("SELECT article.titreArticle, article.textArticle,
    article.idArticle, article.dateArticle, GROUP_CONCAT(images.images) AS IMG
    FROM article LEFT JOIN images
        ON article.idArticle = images.idArticle
    GROUP BY article.idArticle");

    // FIRST LOOP ON ROWS
    for ($i = 0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
    ?>
     <h1 style="text-align: center"><?php echo $row['idArticle']; ?></h1>
        <hr>

        <?php

        $images = ""; // we will store all our images for this row here (if any)

        if($row ['IMG'] !=null ) {
                $value = $row['IMG'];
                $values = explode(",", $value);

                // SECOND LOOP ON IMAGES
                foreach($values, $imgsrc){
                    $images .= '<img style="width: 300px" src="images/'.$imgsrc.'">';
                }

                echo $images; // output all images
        }


        ?>
```